# Return missing from this function?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, return

I'm getting this error "`Missing return in a function expected to return 'NSAttributedString`?'"

Can someone please help? I'm beating my small brain--prone to idiot mistakes--out over this thing. I put the "`dummyString`" line in to ensure there was a return, but no luck.

TIA

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let dummyString = "Dummy String"


    if component == 1 {
        return NSAttributedString(string: denomArray[row], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow])

    }else if component == 0 {
        if issuerArray [row] == "US" {
            return NSAttributedString(string: self.issuerArray[row], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: BaseViewController.Flag.us.themeColor])
        }
        if issuerArray [row] == "Canada" {
            return NSAttributedString(string: self.issuerArray[row], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: BaseViewController.Flag.canada.themeColor])
        }

    }else{
        return NSAttributedString(string: dummyString, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the construct of your `if component == 0` block. If the country is neither US nor Canada then there is no return.  You may know that the row can only contain one of those two values, but the compiler doesn't.

The simplest fix is to make the default `return` non-conditional. That way, if no previous `return` has been executed, you will return the default value.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let dummyString = "Dummy String"

    if component == 1 {
        return NSAttributedString(string: denomArray[row], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow])

    } else if component == 0 {
        if issuerArray [row] == "US" {
            return NSAttributedString(string: self.issuerArray[row], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: BaseViewController.Flag.us.themeColor])
        }
        if issuerArray [row] == "Canada" {
            return NSAttributedString(string: self.issuerArray[row], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: BaseViewController.Flag.canada.themeColor])
        }
    }
    return NSAttributedString(string: dummyString, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])

}
```

Comment: That fixed it, and also taught me a valuable lesson. Thanks very much, good sir!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `return nil` above the last line.